Linux 6.8.0-40 don't boot on mac book air 6.1
I have a Mac Book air 6.1 that worked fine with Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS kernel  linux 6.5.0-45; after a recent upgrade to linux 6.8.0-40 I cannot boot. Everything ok if I choose to start with previous kernel (linux 6.5.0-45).
What can I do?
Thanks

Are you using closed source kernel modules?  (such as NVidia), as one option maybe switching from the HWE kernel stack (22.04.4 used 6.5, 22.04.5 uses 6.8) to GA kernel stack (5.15).  Your system will allow multiple kernel stacks installed (you can select at grub during boot) though some kernel modules (eg. NVidia) can prevent this, both getting security updates (where as 6.5 kernel doesn't). This is a safer option (than using 6.5) whilst issues with HWE/6.8 are explored.

Everything ok if I choose to start with previous kernel (linux 6.5.0-45)

If you ignore the security risks of using an EOL kernel, using the 6.5 kernel is fine.  The security risks are moot if your machine is used offline and not sharing media with other devices on local networks etc, but we cannot know how you use your machine; if it's stand alone or network/internet based... which is why I suggested the GA kernel stack which gets security fixes.
